# Find overlapping circles

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, computational-geometry

I have a rectangular area where there are circles with equal radius. I want to find which circles overlap with other circles (the output is a list of 2-element sets of overlapping circles).

I know how to check if two of the circles overlap (the distance between their centers is less than the diameter). I can perform this check for every pair of circles, but I was wondering if there is a better algorithm (faster than `O(n^2)`).

EDIT

The number of circles is usually about 100 and overlappings won't happen very often.

Here is some context:
The rectangle is a battlefield in a game. The movement of the units is done on small steps and I'm trying to detect collisions between units.

Comment: Nice question. :) It seems to me you could do some sort of sweep-line algorithm.

Comment: Hmmm . . . all circles could overlap with all other circles.  To me, that suggests that you cannot do better than O(n^2) in the worst case -- although there might be heuristics to optimize that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think there should be an output-sensitive algorithm---one that runs in time proportional to the number of overlaps (and the number of circles); this is the case with the somewhat related segment-intersection problem.

Comment: Your question is not precise enough. What is the expected output ? `n` circles can form a chain where anyone of them overlaps with exactly and only two others. What would be the output in this case ?

Comment: How large is `n` ?

Comment: n is usually about 100

Comment: Is the set of circles dense or sparse ? Are overlaps frequent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the new explanation of the problem statement, I would recommend a different approach.

Overlay a square grid over the battlefield, with a grid step equal to one circle diameter. Every circle can overlap at most four cells. In each cell, keep a list of the overlapping circles (and update it on every move).

Detecting potential collisions will now take about four cell/circle tests per circle, i.e. close to linear time.

Answer (score 2):

For a simple solution, insert the centers in a 2d-tree and perform circular range queries around every center with a query radius 2R. In good conditions, this can be O(N Log(N)).

---

Alternatively, just sort the centers on X and try all circles in turn: by dichotomic search, locate the abscissa Xc and scan to Xc-2R and to Xc+2R, then check the 2D distance.

The cost of the dichotomic searches will be O(N Log(N)). If the circles are uniformly spread out in a square of side S, a stripe of width 4R contains 4RN/S circles, hence a total comparison cost of 4RN²/S. This is a good performance if S is large (think that for N tightly packed circles in a square, S~2R√N, hence 2N√N comparisons).

Comment: Given the low value of N, not sure that this can beat exhaustive search :(

Answer (score 2):

Direct answer: You cannot get better than O(n^2) in general since the circles could potentially all overlap, so you have to generate n^2 answers.

If you get more specific, you might get better answers. For example, if what you are really trying to do is find bounding spheres in a 2D simulation, you can profit from the fact that entities only move so far between frames, if the circles are sparse it's different from when they are tightly packed, etc. So let us know more about what it's all about.

EDIT: You edited your question - you indeed are looking for collision detection in a 2D simulation. If you check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection , they point to several algorithms for exactly your case.

I like the one detailed right on that page where you keep one list of bounding intervals per axis (2 in "2D") and only need to "work hard" when those bounding intervals (which are themself by definition one-dimensional) change (i.e., there "overlap state"). This removes the `O(n²)` for well-behaved cases. They don't give an estimate for the complexity of that, but as it basically comes down to sorting, it looks more or less `O(n logn)` to me, and less when there are only minimal changes between frames.

Comment: O(N²), indeed unavoidable at worst, is most probably pessimistic.

Comment: Yes, pointing that out was my intention - if the OP gives us more specific information, we can think about other solutions. So he did, in fact, I'll edit the answer. :)