# How to make multiple circle objects not go into each other with collision detection?

Tags: javascript, vector, collision-detection, game-physics

I have a total of 1 to 64 blobs and they all move to my mouse position. But i want them to not go into each other, in other words circle collision detection. However i can't seem to make it smooth and also push new objects after they move for the first time?

Tried checking each blob for collision with other blobs. If collosion is true, then set the distance between the blobs to their accumulated radiuses.

This is how i wrote the colliding function, but this way of doing it makes the resetting of positions too fast. I want it to be a smooth, but fast transition. Like instead of now 1 frame, lets say 10 frames. And another problem is when two objects' are distanced to their radiuses, they might collide into new ones and that will cause this code to run again, and then all blobs go crazy.

```
this.collide = function() {
   var length = this.blobs.length; // How many blobs?

   this.blobs.forEach(function(item, index) {
      for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

         // Get absolute distance between two vectors
         var v0 = vectorFromTo(blob.blobs[i].pos.x, blob.blobs[i].pos.y, //[x2, y2]
                               item.pos.x, item.pos.y); //[x1, y1]

         // if colliding, set distance between to their accumulated radiuses
         if (magnitude(v0) < blob.blobs[i].r + item.r) {
         item.pos.add(v0.setMag(magnitude(v0) - (blob.blobs[i].r + item.r))); 
         }
      }
   });
}
```

I haven't tried to code another way of doing this yet because i haven't learned about vectors in school, but i do understand them quite a bit. But what i think would work is if i checked for collision, and if they collide they go opposite directions 50% of the deficit distance, and then they check if they hit new blobs. But this would require physics right? Cause then it would have to do something with the mass and speed of the blob as well to know whats gonna happen to the new blob it crashes into?

EDIT:

This is what im looking for: https://youtu.be/QvlhRGtlcsw

This is what it currently looks like: https://youtu.be/QEpHnCgomqY

Comment: Concerning the collision detection: The 'easy' way is to think of your blobs as squares or nested squares instead of circles, so you do not have to do radial calculations. But that's not as pretty. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401562/find-overlapping-circles could help? The big science ways can be found on other sites, like https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16927/efficient-algorithm-to-find-overlapping-circles-of-various-sizes  . Concerning the smooth transitions: Use `requestAnimationFrame()` to move the blobs. This will try to sync to the FPS of the monitor.

Comment: That was a lot of new words for me, but if i understood it correctly it wasn't really what i was looking for. I added some links to give a visual representation of how i want it to look and what it looks like now. The collision detection seems to be fine, but im just not sure how to make them interact with each other correctly when there are more than 2 circles. Maybe i need to check if each circle has any acting forces on it from other circles being pushed? Also, thanks for such a quick reply :)

Comment: When you're doing is usally done with a timestep. Every physics frame you calculate the displacement of your objects, and check for intersections. If you have a collision, you simulate it according to some law (usually a totally rigid body ellastic collision, where forces are applied to both objects, and they are moved). This approach has a problem with 'tunelling', if your objects are moving very fast. In that case, you would need an algorithm for 'continious collision detection'.

Comment: Alright, i will look into it and see if i can make some changes to make it work :) Appreciate you taking your time to help.