# How can I draw the points of a route equidistant of one another?

Tags: java, optimization, gis

I am writing a program that outputs the shortest route between two points on a map. The problem is that if the route is too long and it has many points that define its path it slows the program a lot and I am looking for a way to draw just some points instead of all the points in the array.

My approach goes as follows: the map has a zoom, each time the zoom changes check which points overlaps with the others. All the points that doesn't overlap go into the `routeToDraw` list and then it is drawn.

To check if the points overlap or not I have the following function:

```
    //route is a list of latitude and longitude points

    LinkedList<Point.Double> route = MapPanel.this.getGlassPane().getRoute();
    LinkedList<Point.Double> routeToDraw = new LinkedList<Point.Double>();
    int ovalSize = 8;
    boolean compareMorePoints;
    for(int i = 0; i < route.size(); i++) {
         Point p1 = getScreenCoordinates(route.get(i).x, route.get(i).y);       
         compareMorePoints = true;
         int j = i + 1;
         while (j < route.size() && compareMorePoints == true) {
             Point p2 = getScreenCoordinates(route.get(j).x, route.get(j).y);
             
             if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1.x  - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2)) > ovalSize ) {
                 routeToDraw.add(route.get(i));
                 compareMorePoints = false;
             }
             j++;
         }
    }
    MapPanel.this.getGlassPane().setRouteToDraw(routeToDraw);
```

The problem is that this function is [quite expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36402823/12293801) and although it does reduce the amount of points to draw and I seem to obtain some speed after calculating `routeToDraw` I don't think it is worth the wait each time I zoom in or out.

The ideal solution would be something like Google Maps' does when routing, drawing a series of equidistant points that modify each time you zoom in or out and look quite nice.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions...

1. (old trick)...  Don't do unnecessary math inside of a loop.  You can and should eliminate the `sqrt` function, which is an "expensive" math operation when doing distances.  Just compare to the square of `ovalSize`.  It is mathematically equivalent.
2. Is your list sorted in any way?  If there were a convenient point in your program to sort your list (or a copy of it) before displaying, then you could very quickly:

- Lop off the first and last part that is outside your zoom window in one of the coordinates (say X, if you sorted by X) by doing a binary search for the window boundary
- Tighten up your loop to only look at neighbors within a window of concern, and do a sliding window instead of all-compared-to-all.

Comment: 1. Just changed the sqrt for ovalSize*ovalSize which as you say should be faster.

2. The list is sorted from start point to finish point.

2.1. I don't know what is a binary seach but I am already checking before drawing which points are inside the window and which ones aren't, however this is done in the draw function as you can move around the map without changin the zoom.

2.2. I've thought about this one but the problem I find to this solution is that I'll need to set a different and arbitrary amount of neighbours to check depending on the zoom level. I'll try anyway. 

Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest using binary search to find the "lop-off" point in the front and back of the array quickly (vice checking all points sequentially).  The sliding window...yes, an arbitrary number of points, probably using a `while` loop, which is good for loops of arbitrary size based on condition.  It would be a little complicated to check for overlaps in x and y that mutually conflict, so maybe other approaches are viable.